# Simple Kendo UI application will not show the search bar for .AutoComplete()

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get started with Kendo UI by doing a simple autocomplete. But the issue I'm having is that the Kendo UI elements are not showing. Elements being the search bar. I even tried using datepicker and that still won't show.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "HomePage";
}
@{ 
    var countries = new String[] {
                "America",
                "Ansonia",
                "Latvia",
                "Italy",
                "Lithuania"};
        }
<br/>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>
    @{ 
        Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                        .Name("myAutoCompletion")
                        .Placeholder("Country")
                        .BindTo(@countries);
    }
<div/>
```

Comment: i dont see any html you are attaching the autocomplete to

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. How would I go about attaching the autocomplete to an HTML

Comment: remove the enclosing braces

Comment: you do have an extra brace after Lithunia

Comment: @MikeDebela I think those are necessary for Razor

Comment: That brace closes out the creation of the array, "countries". I'm not receiving any compile errors

Comment: `@Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("myAutoCompletion").Placeholder("Country").BindTo(countries)`

Comment: That only gives me errors @MikeDebela

Comment: reference here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index

Comment: Yeah.. instead of {} I was supposed to use (). Now I can see the text box, but the auto complete isn't working.

Comment: did you try .BindTo(new string[] { "America", "Ansonia", "Latvia", "Italy" })

Comment: also change div to input and see if that works